# How to save watch windows in IAR? They dont save when closing/reopening application

Tags: c, ide, embedded, arm, iar

Is there a way to save the watch windows in IAR Embedded Workbench for ARM so they dont keep disappearing whenever I close/reopen the application?  I have several watch windows to keep an eye on groups of variables and having to repopulate them every time I open up IAR is a real pain.  Is there a way to save the watch windows setup so that I dont have to set them up each time I open up IAR Embedded Workbench?

Comment: +1 for a question I ask myself everyday

Answer (score 2):

IAR (I'm running Embedded Workbench - ARM 5.3) saves this information in a `settings/<projectname>.dbgdt` file under the project's directory.  Make sure the IDE can create and write to this file.

If that file has been put into source control (which it probably shouldn't be), it might be read-only depending on the version control system you're using.